# Tableau: Option for "ALL" disappears from filter options when filtering across multiple data sources

Tags: filter, data-visualization, tableau-api

I'm pretty new to Tableau, using Tableau Desktop 8.2

I have mutliple data sources and am looking to have filters apply to all sheets within the dashboard when a filter is changed.

Following the steps in [this](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/filter-data-sources) Tableau KnowledgeBase article, I was able to accomplish this.

However, when I add the newly created parameter/calculated field filter to the dashboard, I no longer get the option to filter on "all".

So, when I just used regular filters in the individual sheets and filtered on "Area", I saw selections for Areas 1-7 (all of them), plus an option for All, which essentially removes the filter and shows the results for the entire network, right?

Now, however, I am forced to choose one of the seven, eliminating the ability to view results for the full network.

Any ideas on what I am missing? Thanks for any help.

(I literally followed the exact steps in that article, so sorry for linking instead of describing my process- hope that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your your filter calculation to something like this 
[Sub-Category Parameter]="(All)"
OR
[Sub-Category Parameter]=[Sub-Category]

An article can be found here.

http://vizwiz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/tableau-tip-adding-all-filter-option-to.html